# Boto CloudSearch on GAE: TypeError: request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'config'

Tags: google-app-engine, boto, amazon-cloudsearch

I'm using Boto 2.8 on GAE to search and index docs to AWS CloudSearch. When I try to index a document I get the following error:

```
TypeError: request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'config'
```

Surfing the web suggests there is a version compatibility issue with the request library.

The issue seems to come from lines 189-199 of boto/cloudsearch/document.py

```
request_config = {
        'pool_connections': 20,
        'keep_alive': True,
        'max_retries': 5,
        'pool_maxsize': 50
    }

    r = requests.post(url, data=sdf, config=request_config,
        headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
```

If I remove "config=request_config", I can successfully index documents and do not get the error. But what are the ramifications of removing the config argument?

Comment: What version of requests is being provided on GAE?