# boto 2.8.0 and cloudseach

Tags: boto, amazon-cloudsearch

Hi I am trying to add documents to a cloudsearch domain as per

http://docs.pythonboto.org/en/latest/cloudsearch_tut.html#adding-documents-to-the-index

my code snppet is:

```
import boto
conn = boto.connect_cloudsearch(aws_access_key_id='<>',aws_secret_access_key='<>')
domain = conn.lookup('testfoo')
doc_service = domain.get_document_service()
doc_service.add(doc_id, version, data)
```

First I got the same requests issues
[Boto CloudSearch on GAE: TypeError: request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'config'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14719603/boto-cloudsearch-on-gae-typeerror-request-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument)

and so I removed the config kwarg (also not sure of the consequences)
and then I get

```
boto.cloudsearch.document.CommitMismatchError: Incorrect number of adds returned. Commit: 1 Response: 0
```

My data is like this

```
[
{
        "raw" : "whole bunch of raw text",
        "title" : "My new title",
        "blurb" : "A really exciting article",
        "document_type" : "Tech Guide",
        "url" : "http://www.foobar/7199/tech-advice"
}
]
```

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: I now downgraded requests from 1.1.0 to 0.14.2 to see if this would fix anything but it does not help

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the problem is when I built up the json in data it is not json but a string. So when this produces the json being sent to the cloudsearch domain and it combines the id and "Add" operation it includes "fields": "[
{
        "raw" : "whole bunch of raw text",
        "title" : "My new title",
        "blurb" : "A really exciting article",
        "document_type" : "Tech Guide",
        "url" : "http://www.foobar/7199/tech-advice"
}
]" as a string

The solution is simply data needs json encoding

doc_service.add(doc_id, version, **json.loads(data)**)

Answer (score 0):

Here just remove [] from data. Because if you have single object then you must pass it with dictionay.  {}

***[***
{
        "raw" : "whole bunch of raw text",
        "title" : "My new title",
        "blurb" : "A really exciting article",
        "document_type" : "Tech Guide",
        "url" : "http://www.foobar/7199/tech-advice"
}
***]***